# Why does ArrayBlockingQueue signal 'not full' after catching InterruptedException?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-6

In [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html), inside the `put` method, why does it call `notFull.signal()` after catching `InterruptedException`? When the thread is going to terminate, why does it send out a 'not full' signal?

From the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java#ArrayBlockingQueue.put%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
        if (e == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        final E[] items = this.items;
        final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            try {
                while (count == items.length)
                    notFull.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                notFull.signal(); // propagate to non-interrupted thread
                throw ie;
            }
            insert(e);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that I tagged with Java 6 since Open JDK's [Java 7 implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java#ArrayBlockingQueue.put%28java.lang.Object%29) appears to have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the following scenario:

- Threads 1 and 4 are waiting on `notFull`, *ie*, the queue is full, and the lock is released.
- Thread 2 holds the lock, and is about to remove an element from the queue.
- Thread 3 interrupts Thread 1.

Now imagine the following interleaving:

```
+-+--+--------+-----------+------- TIME +---+------------+---------------------->
| |  |        |           |             |   |            |
+---------+   +------------------+      +----------+     |
| Thread2 |   |      Thread2     |      | Thread2  |     |
|  lock() |   | notFull.signal() |      | unlock() |     |
+---------+   +------------------+      +----------+     |
  |  |                    |                 |            |
  +---------------------+ |                 |            |
  |       Thread3       | |                 |            |
  | Thread1.interrupt() | |                 |            |
  +---------------------+ |                 |            |
     |                    |                 |            |
     +---------------+    +-------------+   +---------+  +----------------------+
     |   Thread1     |    |   Thread1   |   | Thread1 |  |       Thread1        |
     | interrupted() |    | signalled() |   |  lock() |  | InterruptedException |
     +---------------+    +-------------+   +---------+  +----------------------+
```

What if `InterruptedException` wasn't caught, and Thread 1 was just to unlock and abandon the wait? What would happen to Thread 4, who was still waiting for a signal on `notFull`? The signal had already been sent by Thread 2, but it just so happened that the receiving thread, Thread 1, had been interrupted, and the signal was *wasted*.

In short: If the thread received a signal when it was also interrupted, it passes along the signal to another thread, so that it isn't lost. This prevents threads from waiting indefinitely for something that already happened.

Comment: +1 Good explanation and diagram. Would you mind commenting on the differences with the Java 7 version (linked in my comment above)? I'm trying to see how it's different and why it would have changed.

Comment: @Paul Bellora: I don’t know whether it really was ever necessary, but by looking at the Java 7 code of `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.ConditionObject` which is the back-end for the `wait` functionality it becomes clear that it is not necessary with this implementation. Consuming a signal and receiving an `InterruptedException` are mutually exclusive. So there is no need to catch the exception and re-signal.

Comment: @PaulBellora As @Holger said, looking at the Java 7 code for `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.ConditionObject` tells us that resignalling is no longer necessary. Any thread interrupted before a signal won't be signalled. The code is different in Java 6, so it *might* have been necessary then. Although, the significant part (method `doSignal`) remained unchanged.